# get specific value from string based on separator

Tags: apex, string, substring

I have a code

```
    String[] base = new String[]{'my father | name is | bryan luke','my mother | go to | shopping mall'};
    for(integer i=0; i < base.size(); i++) {
    String output = base[i];
    List<String> outputList = base[i].split('|');

    system.debug( 'this is : '+output);
}
```

how can I just get the value of 'name is' and 'go to'?

Thanks!

Comment: So you just need the 2nd chunk of the splitted string, always? If not could you please elaborate your requirement?

Comment: hmm for now is yes, but how if i need to get 'my father' and 'my mother' too? @SantanuHalder
can u post your first code when just need 2nd chunk of splitted string,?
and the second code if need first chunk and 2nd chunk?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `outputList` that you have is nothing but a string array with index starting from 0. You access it just like you access any other array i.e `outputList[index]`

Update your for loop to this:

```
for(integer i=0; i < base.size(); i++) {
  List<String> outputList = base[i].split('[|]');
  System.debug('1st chunk is '+outputList[0]);
  System.debug('2nd chunk is '+outputList[1]);
  System.debug('3rd chunk is '+outputList[2]);
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work as i want sir,
all i want to achieve is to printout:
name is & go to @santanuHalder

Comment: Then just print `outputList[1]`, remove the other debug statements.

Comment: oh i just see my old debug log, sorry sir! it work! thanks anywany! @santanuHalder

Comment: Glad! I could help.

Comment: yup, but the code not working well, 

List<String> outputList = base[i].split('|');  must be
List<String> outputList = base[i].split('[|]');
i already request to edit, jsut accpt my revision of your answer sir, so the other can get this well code in the future @SantanuHalder

Comment: OKay its for the `|` character. That's something new I came to know today. Thanks buddy. Answer updated!

Comment: u can try this code if want to know why we need [],  
just paste this code sir! and u will get the answer @SantanuHalder 
String[] selectedEmployee = new String[]{'ab|cd|ef', 'gh|ij|kl'};
   for(integer i=0; i < selectedEmployee.size(); i++) {
                String s = selectedEmployee[i];
                String[] sList = selectedEmployee[i].split('|');
                system.debug(sList[1]);
   }